# Gitlab docker image script - if condition is not working

Tags: bash, docker, shell, gitlab-ci

Written a below gitlab pipeline using python image and if condition works perfectly fine.

```
.chk-bracket:
  image: "python:3.7"
  before_script:
    - apt update
    - apt install jq -y 
    - pip install awscli
    
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE
    - |
      if [[ $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE = *"_test"* ]]; then
        echo "testing"
      fi
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^develop/ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*build_test.*/
```

Later we refactored to use docker image instead of python image and the if condition started failing, it's not printing testing. Of course I simplified with the simple if condition in the original complex gitlab pipeline code

```
.chk-bracket:
  image: "docker:stable"
  before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk add py-pip jq bash
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE
    - |
      if [[ $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE = *"_test"* ]]; then
        echo "testing"
      fi
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^develop/ && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*build_test.*/
```

Any clues to why this condition is not working in docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [python:3.7](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/3.7/images/sha256-3f2cf67e2e590a87741ad3bfc9b5de182e5d76eee88ee6ad191ebe9895e65ffd?context=explore) uses debian as its base image and [docker:stable](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/docker/stable/images/sha256-18d39b6848cecae067cc0d94c554029bfc88d3069c80bb5049d54da659249b94?context=explore) uses alpine as its base image, Alpine comes with ash as the default shell instead of bash. I am using below statements inside docker image for substring match.

```
        if [ -z "${CI_COMMIT_TAG##*"dev"*}" ]; then
          echo "Building dev Image..."
          docker build --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG . --build-arg VERSION=$CI_COMMIT_TAG
        fi
```

Comment: Thank you it works with the above condition

Answer (score 1):

As outlined by @antoniomerlin the dind image is alpine.

[There is a ubuntu-dind version](https://github.com/cruizba/ubuntu-dind) and there are maybe more ...

Installing aws cli (v2) in alpine is a real pain,
[there is already a detailed answer how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65969295/13654837)